# Segmentation fault error in C program using MQPUT

Tags: c, ibm-mq

I have a program below

```
#include <stdio.h>    
#include <cmqc.h>    
#include <cmqxc.h>    
#include "dte_mq.h"    
#include <string.h>    
#include <stdlib.h>    

typedef struct tagDTE_QUEUE_DESCRIPTOR    
{    
    MQHOBJ handle;    
    int    IsSyncpointControled;    
} DTE_QUEUE_DESCRIPTOR, *PDTE_QUEUE_DESCRIPTOR;    
static MQHCONN sHConn = 0;    
static MQLONG  sCompCode = MQCC_OK;    
static MQLONG  sReason = MQRC_NONE;    
static int     sNumOpenQueues = 0;    
static PDTE_QUEUE_DESCRIPTOR sQueues = NULL;   
MQLONG   OpenCode;    
MQOD     od = {MQOD_DEFAULT};    /* Object Descriptor */    
MQMD     md = {MQMD_DEFAULT};    
MQPMO    pmo = {MQPMO_DEFAULT};    
MQLONG   O_options;    
MQLONG   C_options;     
MQGMO   gmo = {MQGMO_DEFAULT};    
/* MQCONNX options */    
MQCNO   Connect_options = {MQCNO_DEFAULT};    
/* Client connection channel */    
MQCD    ClientConn = {MQCD_CLIENT_CONN_DEFAULT};    

DTE_MQ_RESULT dteMqSend(int qd, void *buf, int len)    
{   
printf("oleg\n");    
/* memcpy(md.Format, MQFMT_STRING, MQ_FORMAT_LENGTH); */    
    md.MsgType  = MQMT_DATAGRAM;    
printf("oleg1\n");    
   memcpy(md.MsgId, MQMI_NONE, sizeof(md.MsgId));    
printf("oleg2\n");    
   memcpy(md.CorrelId, MQCI_NONE, sizeof(md.CorrelId));    
printf("oleg3\n");    
   memcpy(md.Format, MQFMT_STRING, (size_t)MQ_FORMAT_LENGTH);    
printf("oleg4\n");    

   if(sQueues[qd].IsSyncpointControled)    
      pmo.Options |= MQPMO_SYNCPOINT;    
printf("oleg5\n");    
   MQPUT(sHConn, sQueues[qd].handle, &md, &pmo, len, buf, &sCompCode, &sReason);    
   printf("MQput CC=%ld RC=%ld\n", sCompCode, sReason);    
   if (sCompCode != MQCC_OK) return DTE_MQR_FAILED;    

   return DTE_MQR_OK;    
}
```

I put print statement and found out that after printf("oleg4\n";) I get error
    Segmentation fault

Could you please help me top debug the program? Do I have to use malloc for the structure? It is written in C and using MQPUT

Below is a program, where above function is called

```
#include <stdio.h>    
#include <stdlib.h>    
#include <string.h>    

#include <cmqc.h>            /* includes for MQI          */    
#include <cmqxc.h>    


int main(int argc, char **argv)    
{    
    MQLONG   messlen;                /* message length received       */    

    char     QMgrName[MQ_Q_MGR_NAME_LENGTH+1];    
    char     QName[MQ_Q_NAME_LENGTH+1];    
    char     channelName[MQ_CHANNEL_NAME_LENGTH+1];    
    char     hostname[1024];    
    char     port[4];    
    MQLONG   buflen;    
    MQBYTE   TmpBuf[65536] = "This is a simple test message.";    
    int msgsToGet;    
    int msgsGot;    
    int dteretinit;    
    int dteretdeinit;    
    int dteretopen;    
    int dteretclose;    
    int qd;    
    int dteretput;    

    if (argc != 6)    
    {  
        printf("Usage: NewMQTest QMgrName ChlName hostname port  QName\n");    
        exit(-1);    
    }    


    strncpy(QMgrName, argv[1], MQ_Q_MGR_NAME_LENGTH);    
    QMgrName[MQ_Q_MGR_NAME_LENGTH] = '\0';    

    strncpy(channelName, argv[2], MQ_CHANNEL_NAME_LENGTH);    
    channelName[MQ_CHANNEL_NAME_LENGTH] = '\0';    

    strncpy(hostname, argv[3], 1023);    
    hostname[1023] = '\0';    

    strncpy(port,argv[4],4);    

    strncpy(QName, argv[5], MQ_Q_NAME_LENGTH);    
    QName[MQ_Q_NAME_LENGTH] = '\0';    

    dteretinit = dteMqInit(QMgrName,hostname,channelName);    
    printf("Return code from dteMqInit = %d\n",dteretinit);    
    qd = -1;    
    dteretopen = dteMqOpen(QName, qd);    
    printf ("Return code from dteMqOpen = %d\n",dteretopen);    

   if (dteretopen == 0 )    
   {    
       buflen = strlen(TmpBuf);    
       TmpBuf[buflen + 1] = '\0';    
       dteretput = dteMqSend(qd,*TmpBuf,buflen);    
       printf("return mqput %d\n",dteretput);    
   }    
   dteretclose = dteMqClose(qd);    
   printf("Return code from dteMqClose = %d\n",dteretclose);    

   dteretdeinit = dteMqDeinit();    
   printf("Return code from dteMqDeinit = %d\n",dteretdeinit);    
 }
```

Comment: is `sQueues` part of the library? Because it's not declared in there. Also, how is the function called? What's `qd`'s value?

Comment: Check if `qd` isn't out of range.

Comment: I added calling program and in function all variables declared. Please check again

Comment: the value of qd = -1

Comment: If your question is related to IBM MQ please use the [ibm-mq] tag, not the [mq] tag.

Comment: ok, but can you help me to find the problem?

Comment: Looks like segmentation fault is on MQPUT. Can somebody help me with this? is the problem with sQueues[qd].handle?

Comment: qd should not = -1.  QD is supposed to be the MQHOBJ to the queue from the call to dteMqOpen.  Does dteMqOpen initialize sQueues for qd?

Comment: yes, but it is separate function. It doesn't return qd. Should I change it to another value?

Comment: It must be the value returned by the MQOPEN.  You can't go directly to MQPUT without first getting a handle from MQOPEN.

Comment: by my code I make qd = -1, but send it to MQOPEN and MQOPEN make it +1. Then I make dteMqSend(qd,*TmpBuf,buflen); It qd should be changed to +1, but it still -1, and in the program it is int

Comment: *qd = i;
 sQueues[i].handle = hObj;  It is in my MQOPEN. It just returns ok or nor OK. Should I change to return OK and qd?

Comment: qd when passed to MQPUT should be the value returned by MQOPEN not -1 or +1 either of those would be invalid for MQPUT.

Answer (score 0):

I analyzed my program and check MQ. SSL didn't let me connect to MQ, that is why I couldn't change qd. The program is very old, and when failed, return value was set up as 0, 1 is success. I never did it like that. 0 is always success.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is some bad code.

```
typedef struct tagDTE_QUEUE_DESCRIPTOR
{
    MQHOBJ handle;
    int    IsSyncpointControled;
} DTE_QUEUE_DESCRIPTOR, *PDTE_QUEUE_DESCRIPTOR;

static PDTE_QUEUE_DESCRIPTOR sQueues = NULL;

if(sQueues[qd].IsSyncpointControled)
```

In the code that you have posted, 'sQueues' is never set, so that is why it is throwing segmentation fault on the 'if' statement. And if 'qd' is really '-1' as per your comment, then I have to wonder what in the world you are doing.

```
dteretinit = dteMqInit(QMgrName,hostname,channelName);
```

How come you don't pass the port number into the dteMqInit subroutine?